# setState in nested arrays in react

Tags: reactjs, nested, state, setstate

I have a React state object with two arrays inside of it.

```
this.state = {
  data2: {
    nodes: [{id: 'input'}],
    links: []
  },
};
```

I want to add new values to these arrays after some user action but I haven't figured out the right way. So far I have attempted something like this:

```
this.setState([...this.state.data2, {nodes: [...this.state.nodes,{ id: 'input2'}]}]);
```

Any ideas on how should I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend something like this

```
this.state = { 
    data2: {
    nodes: [],
    links: []
  },
};
```

when you set your state you dont have to use the this keyword inside the `setState function`

```
this.setState({ data2:{ nodes: [{id:'input1'},{id:'input2'}]} })
```

you can push objects in nodes array too

```
let temp = data2
temp.nodes.push({id:'input3'})
this.setState({ data2:temp })
```

Comment: this could work too..

this.setState({ data2: Object.assign({}, this.state.data2, { nodes: [...this.state.data2.nodes, {id: 'input1'}, {id: 'input2'}] }) })

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in two simple ways. One which you did, using spread operator. Something like this,

`this.setState({data2: {...this.state.data2, nodes: [{id: "input1"}]} });`

Or you can use `[Object.assign()][1]` like this,

`this.setState({data2: Object.assign({}, this.state.data2, nodes: [{id: "input1"}])});`